# Issue with retrieveing the Manager of a System User in a Custom workflow - CRM 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Issues with custom workflow activity in CRM 2013 On-prem

I'm trying to pass the Manager of the System

here is the code that I'm running, it gets to setting the MANAGER and stops

I put the ran the FetchXML seperatly and it does return a value so I know what bit works

```
    public class CaseAccountManagerManagersLookup : CodeActivity
{
    // Inputs
    [Input("Enter Case")]
    [ReferenceTarget("incident")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> CA { get; set; }

    // Outputs
    [Output("Manager Output")]
    [ReferenceTarget("systemuser")]
    public OutArgument<EntityReference> AMOUT { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        // Context
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        //Create the tracing service
        ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

        // get the account and renewals manager ID's
        var CASE = CA.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext);
        tracingService.Trace("Case ID = " + CASE.Id);
        try
        {
            // FETCH
            string fetchXml = string.Format(@"  
              <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
              <entity name='incident'>
                <attribute name='title' />
                <attribute name='incidentid' />
                <order attribute='title' descending='false' />
                <filter type='and'>
                  <condition attribute='incidentid' operator='eq' value='{0}' />
                </filter>
                <link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='customerid' alias='ak'>
                  <link-entity name='account' from='accountid' to='parentcustomerid' alias='al'>
                    <link-entity name='systemuser' from='systemuserid' to='bc_dssalesperson' alias='am'>
                        <attribute name='parentsystemuserid' />
                    </link-entity>
                  </link-entity>
                </link-entity>
              </entity>
            </fetch>", CASE.Id);

            EntityCollection case_results = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
            //tracingService.Trace("fetch has run");
            if (case_results.Entities.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var a in case_results.Entities)
                {
                    //if (a.Attributes.Contains("ai_parentsystemuserid"))
                    //{
                        tracingService.Trace("set manager id next");
                        var MANAGERID = (EntityReference)a.Attributes["parentsystemuserid"];
                        tracingService.Trace("manager id set");
                        AMOUT.Set(executionContext, MANAGERID);
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Want to see trace");
                    //}
                }
            }
            tracingService.Trace("end ");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Plugin - CaseAccountManagerManagerLookup - " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Want to see trace");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use am.parentsystemuserid instead of just parentsystemuserid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the guid that you are passing is in the correct form?

{8B8099A6-8B89-E411-883D-D89D676552A0}

this is what i get from the export but you are writing

8B8099A6-8B89-E411-883D-D89D676552A0

Also are you sure about the record that you are trying to retrieve? Is the chain complete with data?

case-> contact -> account -> parent user -> parent user ?